# How do I get the base parent folder of an installed application?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, ClamWin.exe is installed in the "ClamWin" folder, which contains a lib and bin folder, however just using "Path".parent returns me the bin folder,  I will to go all the way up to the ClamWin folder and ensure that it will work for the other applications
eg Minecraft.exe in Minecraft folder
avp.exe in the kaspersky folder

Using python

Comment: It seems that it's difficult to know which one is the base: `Path.parent` or `Path.parent.parent` or `Path.parent.parent.parent`

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to ignore the bin folder of the executables? in the case of ClamWin.exe instead of c:\clamwin\bin\ you want c:\clamwin\ ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is only used on windows, I think you can consider using the registry to obtain the path: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Bandizip.exe`

If you get the parent folder recursively until you reach 'Program Files', this may not be universal